# 06 Sienna 3.3 has irritating random misfired, but no light

Tags: toyota, sienna, random-misfire

How can one go about troubleshooting occasional missing when no light or code is generated?  This Sienna has 155k, and hasn't ever had a formal tune up, just good oil and air maintenance.  The 3 rear plugs have never been out as they are a royal pain, but if the front 3 are an indication,  they would be fine.  Clean and just barely any normal wear.  A complete set of coil packs might fix it,  but I hate "shotgunning " parts ... Any thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I take it you've never done the O2 sensors then, either? Ever look at the live data to see how things are functioning? Are you sure it's a misfire and not something else?

Comment: Thanks...  I just very recently changed bank 1 sensor 2 for heater fail code ( I forget the code) .  But that's it.  The missing has been happening for months.  I have a Zurich zr11 reader,  but not really trained in how to read most of the live data.  Would love to learn if anyone knows any shortcuts to that end ...   Ed

Comment: Here's another tidbit ... months ago, it did throw a misfire code for cylinder 4.  Happened during a hard acceleration to pass.  I swapped coil packs 4 & 6 to see if the code would move, and it's never done it again. Even driving hard trying to reproduce it...   Thats also when i pulled the 3 front plugs and they all looked good.